# Range issues when computing linear interpolation in matlab

Tags: matlab

I need help with Interp1 (linear method from matlab). 
The problem goes as follow:

I have a vector, with function values called fx.

```
fx = 1.0e+03 *

2.0500
-0.0005
-0.0005
-0.0004
-0.0003
-0.0004
-0.0005
-0.0005
-0.0006
-0.0007
-0.0008
-0.0008
-0.0009
-0.0010
-0.0011
-0.0011
-0.0012
-0.0013
-0.0013
-0.0014
-0.0015
-0.0015
-0.0016
-0.0016
-0.0017
-0.0018
-0.0018
-0.0019
-0.0019
-0.0020
-0.0020
-0.0021
-0.0022
-0.0022
-0.0023
-0.0023
-0.0024
-0.0024
-0.0025
-0.0025
-0.0026
-0.0027
-0.0027
-0.0028
-0.0028
-0.0029
-0.0029
-0.0030
-0.0030
-0.0031
-0.0031
-0.0032
-0.0032
-0.0033
-0.0033
-0.0034
-0.0034
-0.0035
-0.0035
-0.0036
-0.0036
-0.0037
-0.0037
-0.0038
-0.0038
-0.0038
-0.0039
-0.0039
-0.0040
-0.0040
-0.0041
-0.0041
-0.0042
-0.0042
-0.0043
-0.0043
-0.0043
-0.0044
-0.0044
-0.0045
-0.0045
-0.0046
-0.0046
-0.0046
-0.0047
-0.0047
-0.0048
-0.0048
-0.0048
-0.0049
-0.0049
-0.0050
-0.0050
-0.0050
-0.0051
-0.0051
-0.0051
-0.0052
-0.0052
-0.0053
-0.0053
-0.0053
-0.0054
-0.0054
-0.0054
-0.0055
-0.0055
-0.0055
-0.0056
-0.0056
-0.0056
-0.0057
-0.0057
-0.0057
-0.0057
-0.0058
-0.0058
-0.0058
-0.0059
-0.0059
-0.0059
-0.0059
-0.0060
-0.0060
-0.0060
-0.0060
-0.0061
-0.0061
-0.0061
-0.0061
-0.0062
-0.0062
-0.0062
-0.0062
-0.0062
-0.0063
-0.0063
-0.0063
-0.0063
-0.0063
-0.0063
-0.0064
-0.0064
-0.0064
-0.0064
-0.0064
-0.0064
-0.0064
-0.0065
-0.0065
-0.0065
-0.0065
-0.0065
-0.0065
-0.0065
-0.0065
-0.0065
-0.0065
-0.0065
-0.0065
-0.0065
-0.0065
-0.0065
-0.0065
-0.0065
-0.0065
-0.0065
-0.0065
-0.0065
-0.0065
-0.0065
-0.0065
-0.0065
-0.0065
-0.0065
-0.0065
-0.0065
-0.0065
-0.0065
-0.0064
-0.0064
-0.0064
-0.0064
-0.0064
-0.0064
-0.0064
-0.0063
-0.0063
-0.0063
-0.0063
-0.0062
-0.0062
-0.0062
-0.0062
-0.0061
-0.0061
-0.0061
-0.0061
-0.0060
-0.0060
-0.0060
-0.0059
-0.0059
-0.0059
-0.0058
-0.0058
-0.0058
-0.0057
-0.0057
-0.0056
-0.0056
-0.0055
-0.0055
-0.0054
-0.0054
-0.0053
-0.0053
-0.0052
-0.0052
-0.0051
-0.0051
-0.0050
-0.0050
-0.0049
-0.0048
-0.0048
-0.0047
-0.0047
-0.0046
-0.0045
-0.0045
-0.0044
-0.0043
-0.0042
-0.0042
-0.0041
-0.0040
-0.0039
-0.0038
-0.0038
-0.0037
-0.0036
-0.0035
-0.0034
-0.0033
-0.0032
-0.0031
-0.0030
-0.0030
-0.0029
-0.0028
-0.0027
-0.0025
-0.0024
-0.0023
-0.0022
-0.0021
-0.0020
-0.0019
-0.0018
-0.0017
-0.0015
-0.0014
-0.0013
-0.0012
-0.0010
-0.0009
-0.0008
-0.0006
-0.0005
-0.0004
-0.0002
-0.0001
 0.0000
 0.0002
 0.0003
 0.0005
 0.0006
 0.0008
 0.0009
 0.0011
 0.0013
 0.0014
 0.0016
 0.0018
 0.0019
 0.0021
 0.0023
 0.0024
 0.0026
 0.0028
 0.0030
 0.0032
 0.0034
 0.0035
 0.0037
 0.0039
 0.0041
 0.0043
 0.0045
 0.0047
 0.0049
 0.0052
 0.0054
 0.0056
 0.0058
 0.0060
 0.0063
 0.0065
 0.0067
 0.0069
 0.0072
 0.0074
 0.0077
 0.0079
 0.0081
 0.0084
 0.0086
 0.0089
 0.0092
 0.0094
 0.0097
 0.0100
 0.0102
 0.0105
 0.0108
 0.0111
 0.0113
 0.0116
 0.0119
 0.0122
 0.0125
 0.0128
 0.0131
 0.0134
 0.0137
 0.0140
 0.0144
 0.0147
 0.0150
 0.0153
 0.0157
 0.0160
 0.0163
 0.0167
 0.0170
 0.0174
 0.0177
 0.0181
 0.0185
 0.0188
 0.0192
 0.0196
 0.0199
 0.0203
 0.0207
 0.0211
 0.0215
 0.0219
 0.0223
 0.0227
 0.0231
 0.0235
 0.0239
 0.0244
 0.0248
 0.0252
 0.0257
 0.0261
 0.0266
 0.0270
 0.0275
 0.0279
 0.0284
 0.0289
 0.0293
 0.0298
 0.0303
 0.0308
 0.0313
 0.0318
 0.0323
 0.0328
 0.0333
 0.0338
 0.0343
 0.0349
 0.0354
 0.0359
 0.0365
 0.0370
 0.0376
 0.0381
 0.0387
 0.0393
 0.0398
 0.0404
 0.0410
 0.0416
 0.0422 
 0.0428
 0.0434
 0.0440
 0.0447
 0.0453
 0.0459 
 0.0466
 0.0472
 0.0479
 0.0485
 0.0492
 0.0499
 0.0505
 0.0512
 0.0519
 0.0526
 0.0533
 0.0540
 0.0547
 0.0554
 0.0562
 0.0569
 0.0576 
 0.0584
 0.0591
 0.0599
 0.0607
 0.0615
 0.0622
 0.0630
 0.0638
 0.0646
 0.0654
 0.0663
 0.0671
 0.0679
 0.0688
 0.0696
 0.0705
 0.0713
 0.0722
 0.0731
 0.0740
 0.0749
 0.0758
 0.0767
 0.0776
 0.0785
 0.0794
 0.0804
 0.0813
```

I have a value for the x-axis

```
x = [0.00111:0.0111:5];
```

I got some help before with computing the interpolation as follows:

```
f = @(xq)interp1(x, fx, xq);
[~, x_t] = ode45(@(t,x)f(x), [0 1], 2);
```

where does the values xq come from?

I am getting some NaN values after solving this ODE. I do not understand why. I believe my fx values and x values are correct, or may be not?The values of *fx* are fixed so I have being changing the values of x many times but with out any look.

Why am I getting NaN values and how can I fix this? What it is outside range?

I know this is not the most interesting and challenging question for many of you but I would really appreciate some help! :)

Thank you in advance!

my results after ODE45 to the interpolated function f:

```
x_t = 
2.0000
1.8696
1.7382
1.6081
1.4810
1.3584
1.2412
1.1304
1.0262
0.9290
0.8388
0.7555
0.6788
0.6084
0.5440
0.4853
0.4319
0.3834
0.3395
0.2999
0.2643
0.2323
0.2038
0.1784
0.1559
0.1360
0.1186
0.1035
0.0903
0.0788
0.0688
0.0601
0.0523
0.0452
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

So you don't have to have your interpolation as a functional handle. `xq` is the x value at which you want to interpolate an f value. So for example if you have this:

```
x = [1 2 3];
fx = [0 4 8];
```

then using linear interpolation, the correct `f` for `x==1.5` would be `2` (i.e. `1.5` is half way between `1` and `2` (x-values), so we get `2` as it's half way between `0` and `4` (fx-values))

However I think you are not using ode45 correctly. The function you pass it needs to be a differential equation, not just an interpolation. But a bunch of observations isn't a D.E., if anything it's a solution to a D.E. So I think you may need to rethink your problem and either gain a better understanding yourself of the D.E. you're trying to solve or else post a lot more information about it.

Comment: Hi @Dan I  apologize very much for the lack of information given in my problem!. I will try to explain my problem better. 
My fx is indeed an ODE.
Generally we write x_dot = f(x) but in my case I do not have the function f(x) explicit. I just have function-values (which is fx).
I have a test function for x_dot (which is given explicit) and a test solution. I have found a metamodel (an approximation of the RHS of x_dot). This metamodel is my fx which is an ODE and discrete function of x, which i want to solve.
I hope this clarifies your questions. I would gladly provide more info is needed.

Comment: Just one more time :D I do not have a bunch of points, I have function values given as a column vector.

Comment: @SergioSarmiento Are you able to (theoretically) solve that by hand? I wouldn't think so... I'm pretty sure you'll need `f` in a functional form to pass to ode45... just have a look at the examples in the docs.

Comment: @SergioSarmiento Becuase what would you be solving for? For `x`? But you already have `x`. To me the solution to something like x_dot = 2*x + x^2 would be solving for g(x) that is expressed without any x_dot terms.

Comment: Hi @Dan it is correct what you say. I can NOT solve theoretically this ODE: dxdt = fx when fx is given discrete ans in order to pass it to ode45 i need a function. Which will be the function after interpolation. I have used this approach to solve (1x1) ,(2x2) and higher systems of ODE which are not linear!, and I did not have problems passing the (interpolated)function to ode45. Just now with this NaN results from one ODE of a (3x3) system. The others are fine :) x_dot = dxdt is the derivative of x (or y,z, etc.) with respect to time and not x. The system is a dynamical system called S-system

Comment: Here is some more info about this S-sytems: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biochemical_systems_theory

Answer (score 1):

I can answer your first question. This is taken from the MATLAB docs:

> vq = interp1(x,v,xq) returns interpolated values of a 1-D function at
>   specific query points using linear interpolation. Vector x contains
>   the sample points, and v contains the corresponding values, v(x).
>   Vector xq contains the coordinates of the query points.

the 'q' in 'xq' stands for "query". You tell MATLAB all the function points `(x, f(x))`, and then ask it to tell you what the function *would be* at `x = xq`.

So your handle function `f` is saying, "you give me an xq, and I'll give you f(xq) as best as I can using interpolation". It wraps `interp1` such that it only needs 1 argument instead of 3.

As for the second question (NaN), can you do the following and tell us what `T` is?

```
[T, x_t] = ode45(@(t,x)f(x), [1,2], 2);
```

Comment: Hi @rangu Thank you for your answer. I have added the T values you asked for. Any clue why the NaN appears?

Comment: Oops; guess we don't need T. My best guess would be that, since `f` is only defined for the range `x=[0.00111, 5]`, ode45 might be integrating past that range. Sorry I can't help further at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to my problem.
The function `fx` (I am saying function even thought I have a vector, this is because i have function values) is just an approximation to my right hand side of an ODE, this goes as follows:

```
x_dot = f(x)
```

where `f` can be a vector or a scalar function and, it can be a linear or nonlinear ODE.

```
fx is ~= f(x) %an approximation to the originally function.
```

This fx is called a metamodel of `f(x)`. This means that `fx` is a simplified model of the real model. For this reason when i interpolate `fx` and solve the ODE:

```
[~, x_t] = ode45(@(t,x)f(x), [0 1], 2);
```

Depending of the initial value, some of the values will lie inside the solution's domain of the metamodel and, in this case, I will get a real value for `x_t`. If some of the values move outside where the metamodel is defined, I will get NaN. Which happens above. Nevertheless, this values are outside the domain of the metamodel but not outside the domain of the real model, which means that the solutions exists but outside my range!
Many thanks to the answers I get before!